# Python data extraction from string

Tags: python

```
page = '{"code":0,"object":{"url":"/1/0/3","deviceObjResource":[{"resourceValue":"\u0000","resourceName":"3"}]},"message":"Activity READ has Operation Completed"}'
```

I Want to extract resourceValue content `\u0000` using Python

Comment: Can you let us know what you've already tried and what has not worked?

Answer (score 1):

Either use regexes as suggested in the previous post, or use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html) module:

```
import json
data = json.loads(page)
data['object']['deviceObjResource'][0]['resourceValue']
```

Comment: Works for me, could you be more specific ?

Comment: for me, it displays `ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 75 (char 74)`

Comment: it is because `\u0000` is interpreted as a single character when you create the string. Use `page = r'{"code":0,"object":{"url":"/1/0/3","deviceObjResource":[{"resourceValue":"\u0000","resourceName":"3"}]},"message":"Activity READ has Operation Completed"}'` and it will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups or [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion.

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<="resourceValue":")[^"]*', page).group()
'\x00'
>>> print(re.search(r'(?<="resourceValue":")[^"]*', page).group())
```

OR

```
>>> re.findall(r'"resourceValue":"([^"]*)', page)
['\x00']
```